# How to remove spaces in VBA when both TRIM function and replace function don't work?

Tags: vba, excel

Okay I know this is a fairly common question but I have done my research and I couldnt find the answer.

I copied a table from the web and pasted in excel sheet.

Then i proceeded to write a macro to process the sheet.

One of the column of numbers didn't work. I found out that it contains spaces in front and back of the number, so `=sum` function couldn't work on it.

So I wrote a simple macro to remove spaces.

```
Sub findandreplacespaces()
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Dim firstrow As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim firstcol As Integer


For i = 1 To 8                             'I've got 8 sheets to process
Worksheets(i).Activate

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row     'define lastrow

    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, 1)).Select
With Selection
    firstrow = .Find(what:="January").Row         'define firstrow
End With

lastcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column    'define lastcolumn

Range(Cells(firstrow, 2), Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Select
Selection.ClearFormats                                     'clear all the formating

For j = 2 To lastcol
For k = firstrow To lastrow

Cells(k, j).Select                                        'select the cell(1,1)

With Selection
    .Replace what:=" ", replacement:="", lookat:=xlPart
End With


Next k
Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

I also tried using `worksheetfunction.TRIM` (selection), not working.

I used `selection.numberformat=general /text/ number`, nope.

One hint though, the numbers that aren't working are all aligned to the left of the cell.

I suspected the cells are locked, so I unlocked them and still the macro didn't work.

Any suggestion on how to deal with this?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
With Selection
    .value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Replace(.value, Chr(160), " ")))
End With
```

The worksheet trim function gets leading and trailing as well as extra inner-string spaces (vba trim only gets leading/trailing). Clean takes out most non-printable characters. the replace on chr(160) removes a type of 'phantom' space.

Comment: fantastic! Thanks for the solution + explanation